# Can I showdown early

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, fold-equity

I'm the last to act. I have pocket queens. First player bets 10, second raises to 30, the fourth raises to 70. I have 160 chips in front of me. I'm willing to go all-in. I decided to believe that there is no better hand than mine (no KK or AA). Therefore, I wish to go all-in and show down my cards right away because I don't want any caller to get lucky and catch an Ace, a King, a small set, a straight, or a flush. Obviously, if they see my queens, they will fold (assuming they don't have KK or AA) which is exactly the outcome I like to get. I know that I got the edge with QQ, but I still wish them to fold. Is it generally allowed to show down early in such a situation, whether it's a cache game or a tournament?

Comment: Just a comment, the problem here is that you don't really have _fold equity_; Your all-in is merely a double raise. i'd guess you're going to be called.

Comment: I think they wouldn't if they knew I've got the edge. Anyway, my question -as you know- is not about the mentioned bet sizes, it's rather about whether this is allowed or not.

Comment: You literally want to intentionally show your hand with hands still live?  And fix cache to cash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am going to ignore the bet amounts and your stack size first and give you a general answer, you have no fold equity anyway.

Well in live, yes you can, there is nothing stopping you from physically turning your hand over and if you're all-in your hand cannot be made dead.

However it is extremely bad etiquette. I have been a poker dealer for 3 years, dealing around the world, I can guarantee you you will get a penalty. Even if a player doesn't call floor on you the dealer should, I know I would. You are effecting the game unfairly and really the dealer's job is to enforce a fair game and a smooth running game. Maybe in a local casino or home game where the rules might be a bit more relaxed, you know the staff, everyone is friendly, you can get away with it, any event or really most places you will get a penalty.

So what you gain in folds will cost you at least a round penalty.

Plus why bother turning your hand face-up? If they have anything beating you they'll call, if they're flipping they'll call. Hell with your stack size the guy who made it 70 will call with any two likely, you'll be beating nearly his entire range anyway.. You're only going to get folds from hands you're crushing which you want to call you. You're just giving information away for free.

Also I would never assume that people you're playing against will, as you put it 'Obviously', do what you want. Everyone plays differently, someone may just decide they don't appreciate you angle shooting and just call you with any two and hope to get lucky.

Comment: In most casino venues, in cash games you are only allowed to show your hand before action is complete when you are head up. Some do not even allow this. In a multi-way hand you may find that showing your hand kills your hand. Don't do it.

Comment: As you single out cash games, can you add something to discuss what would happen in tournament play?

Comment: I actually meant live tournament but I can see your confusion. Cash game you'll likely just be told don't do it again and things will move on. Casino's tend not to want to piss off cash players seen as they don't get any money off them if they up and leave the table.

Comment: In tournament play, you're likely to receive a one-orbit penalty (to include being blinded down when you're in the blinds) -- you will be dealt cards and they will be mucked with you not being permitted to play them.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not. If you are head-up (that is, there is just you and one opponent), then there's nothing wrong with showing cards like this. But once you have two or more opponents it's not just about you anymore. When you show your cards, you are giving information to opponent A that he might be able use against opponent B, and so opponent B is right to be angry with you for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Technically I think if you are all in and show with other hands live then your hand is still live but this is very poor etiquette and should get a penalty

Your odds are just off:

The 70 bet is getting 3:1 pots odd to call
The 30 bet is getting 2.1:1 pot odds to call
And if the 70 bet calls the 30 bet is getting 2.8:1 pot odds to call

All three positions AK is getting pot odds to call

Any Ace or King in the 70 or 30 bet hands is getting pot odds to call

I don't get how you can eliminate AA or KK?   Even the 10 bet could be slow playing AA.

QQ behind a bet and two raises is not that strong of a hand

Answer (score 1):

Frisbee's recent answer raises a good point. QQ just ain't that great here. You are talking about making a cold 5-bet shove without enough fold equity to accomplish your goal.

Also because you're making a cold 5-bet, I think QQ is pretty close to one of the worst possible hands you would have in that spot. Showing the table that your hand is at the very bottom of your possible range there might actually encourage some callers who have equity. You're ultimately going to let people make better decisions against you.

You would have to be really confident in your reads on the other players to make this a good play IMO.

On the question of whether you can show your cards early, I believe doing it intentionally with multiple people left to act should get you a penalty.